# deploy two asp.net core applications which in one solution to nginx

Tags: linux, nginx, deployment, asp.net-core

I'm new to asp.net core and deployment, currently, I have a solution which contains multiple projects, an asp.net core project and a asp.net core web api project in this solution. I want to deploy these two projects to nginx.

I have checked the documentation,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/publishing/linuxproduction

but it is the simple demo project deployment, is there any other resources I can refer?

I have some questions below,

1. Follow the documentation, I copied the files in publish folder to linux and then execute dotnet restore and dotnet run commands. But there's an exception said can't find project.json. Then I tried to copy all of the source files to linux, and then execute restore and run comment, it works. Why?
2. If there're two projects which I need to deploy, like what I said above, how can I do, any guide I can refer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You don't not need to use `dotnet restore` if you are copying the publish folder. It is used only during the development time, not the production. That's why when you include the source code you are able to use it without exceptions. If you are running `dotnet restore` and `dotnet publish` on your development environment and copying only the publish folder to the production environment you only need to run it using dotnet path/to/publishfolder.dll which is done by the service setup in the guide you linked
2. You need to have;

   - You need to add `.UseUrls("http://localhost:XXXX")` on Program.cs, XXXX being the associated port number and different for each project on the same server.
   - Different folders for each project on your server with the respective published files
   - Different service setup for each project.
   - Different server blocks for each project on nginx, with different upstream definitions.

Example, partial nginx configuration;

```
http{

    upstream project1 {
        server localhost:5000;
        ...
    }

    upstream project2 {
        server localhost:5001;
        ...
    }



    server {
        server_name     project1.com;
        ...
        location / {
                    proxy_pass  http://project1;
                    ...
        }
    }

    server {
        server_name     project2.com;
        ...
        location / {
                    proxy_pass  http://project2;
                    ...
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Comment: really thanks for your reply! Since I'm new to .net core and deployment, haven't config nginx before, could you please provide more details or any blogs and resources I can refer?

Comment: @Allen4Tech  The guide you are using includes everything you need. Use that to make sure one of your projects run on the server and then look at what you did. Replicate the parts associated with specific projects. Which are nginx configuration and creating the service part.